# Get week of the year from date in apache drill

Tags: sql, apache, datetime, apache-drill

I'm trying to convert a timestamp in some data (using apache drill) to the week of year.

According to the [reference](https://drill.apache.org/docs/date-time-functions-and-arithmetic/) the closet thing I can see is the "extract" function however this only works for YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND units.

Original date example

```
ID, START_DATE
1, 2014-07-07T13:20:34.000Z
```

Query (something like this)

```
SELECT ID, EXTRACT(WEEK, START_DATE) FROM MY_TABLE;
```

And get a result like this:

```
ID, START_DATE
1, 27
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this problem a few weeks later again and rather than writing a function in drill (as I felt this was to much and I needed just a rough estimate  of a week) I did the following instead:

```
# 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 = 604800

select
  START_DATE as `ORIGINAL DATE`,
  TRUNC(CAST((CAST((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(START_DATE,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(EXTRACT(year FROM TO_DATE(START_DATE, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')),'yyyy')) AS FLOAT) / CAST(604800 AS FLOAT)) AS FLOAT)) + 1 as `WEEK_NO`,
  EXTRACT(year FROM TO_DATE(START_DATE, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')) as `YEAR`
from
  GAME_DATA
order by
  START_DATE
limit 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

Curently, **[Extract function](https://drill.apache.org/docs/date-time-functions-and-arithmetic/#extract-usage-notes)** supports the following time units: YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND.

Example:

```
SELECT ID,EXTRACT(YEAR FROM START_DATE) from dfs.`/home/dev/Desktop/date.csv`;
```

You can create your own function for getting **week of the year**. Check [docs](https://drill.apache.org/docs/develop-custom-functions-introduction/) for developing custom functions.